# phpunit composer install dependicies via symlink

Tags: phpunit, composer-php

I am currently installing phpunit on a per project basis.

This works extremely well, however, the install takes time because I install the directories from cache each time. Is there a way to symlink the directories to one install, or some kind of clever trick I can use to make it do that.

If I do a path repository like this, with phpunit cloned and composer installed on my disk:

```
"require-dev": {
"phpunit/phpunit": "dev-master"
},
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../phpunit",
      "options": {
        "symlink": true
      }
    }
  ],
```

This installs only links the phpunit/phpunit directory, and not the rest of the dependencies like:

```
    "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^5.2",
    "phpunit/php-file-iterator": "^1.4",
    "phpunit/php-text-template": "^1.2",etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer can install packages [globally](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) and then you can refer to the files via it's path, or put the appropriate directory into your PATH variable (in `~/.composer/vendor/bin`). Another, often more popular method is to download the [phpunit.phar](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html) file, and use that to run PHPunit. This also has the advantage of being a single file that can also be committed to a project - though you will want to occasionally update it to the latest version (at least within the major version, 5.7+ or 6.1+). The .Phar file can also be installed globally on the server, in the same way that composer is suggested to.

Comment: I overlooked the global section of that page because I assumed it would be just the global install for just composer itself: much thanks